# Class generic parameter constraint is not passed down to class properties

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I am trying to use TypeScript with [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/) with a generic class. Notice my `AbstractDal` takes a generic parameter where I constraint it such that it has to extend `IEntity` and `IEntity` has a `id` property. But for some reason, `id` property is not passed down to `repository` and it doesn't see that my `findOneBy` function call should type check. I am not sure if it's a TypeScript limitation or a TypeORM limitation.

```
interface IEntity {
  id: number;
}

export abstract class AbstractDal<T extends IEntity> {
  abstract repository: Repository<T>;

  public async get(id: number): Promise<T> {
    return await this.repository.findOneBy({ id });
  }
}
```

Error:

```
src/abstracts/abstract.dal.ts:20:44 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindOptionsWhere<T> | FindOptionsWhere<T>[]'.
  Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhereProperty<NonNullable<T["id"]>, NonNullable<T["id"]>>'.

20     return await this.repository.findOneBy({ id });
```

[Repository](https://github.com/amir734jj/nestjs-template/blob/0377d051d365fd5167cf2a922fad11075ad8364e/src/abstracts/abstract.dal.ts). Just call `npm i && npm start` to see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can explicitly define the type of where statement on findOne() function.

```
 public async get(id: number): Promise<T> {
    const findOptions: FindOneOptions<T> = {
      where: {
        id: id,
      } as FindOptionsWhere<T>,
    };
    return await this.repository.findOne(findOptions);
  }
```

indeed i put AbstractDal class like that

```
export abstract class AbstractDal<T extends Record<string, any> & IEntity>
```